# NetworkManager service error found in journalctl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dell-inspiron

Someone, please can explain me in plain words what this log can mean, so I can try to fix it, I tried all sort of things I found. I'm on a Ubuntu, and switched from gnome to xfce.

`dbus-daemon[767]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=768 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")`

Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04 Focal

Hardware specs: [Dell Inspiron 15 7560-a30s](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15-7560-laptop/docs)

Comment: Add on your post the *Ubuntu version* you are running on and the *hardware setup* too.

Comment: Did you already *reinstall* the NetworkManager?

Comment: hey thx for helping, Ubuntu 20.04 focal, using a dell i15-7560-a30s with a i7-7500U, the link you posted send back to this question, it is right? No and not tried yet.

Comment: [Unconfined Processes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-targeted_policy-unconfined_processes)